# send signal from parent process to child in C

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork

My child proccess can't start to work. I need to pass signal and execute `readUsual` function. 
**This is a small piece of code:**

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid2 = fork(); 
    if (pid2 < 0) 
        printf("Can't create child process\n");
    else if (pid2==0)
    {
        //this block never execute
        printf("Process2, pid=%d\n",getpid());
        signal(SIGUSR1,readUsual); 
    }
    else 
    {
        kill(pid2,SIGUSR1);
        printf("%s\n","Proccess1 end");
        for(;;);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either add synchronization in some way, or call `signal()` before your `fork()`.

With your current code, you have no way to be sure child process call `signal()` before it receive the signal. Receiving the signal before the instruction to handle it will stop the child process.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int received = 0;

void readUsual(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
    {
        received = 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGUSR1,readUsual);

    pid_t pid2 = fork(); 
    if (pid2 < 0)
        printf("Can't create child process\n");
    else if (pid2==0)
    {
        printf("Process2, pid=%d\n",getpid());
        while (!received)
            ;
        printf("SIGUSR1 received.\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        kill(pid2,SIGUSR1);
        printf("%s\n","Proccess1 end");
        while (1)
            ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example of output with this code:

```
Process1 end
Process2, pid=1397
SIGUSR1 received
```

Comment: Thou shalt not printf from a signal handler.

Comment: @alk I did not know, currently DuckDuckGoing it.