# Terminate all child processes using SIGTERM

Tags: c, system-calls

So I have a project in which i should be able to terminate all child processes via signal.
I am wondering how can I send a SIGTERM to all those processes given that i have a id array with all the child id's. That signal should be sent when i receive as argument from main the command "exitNow". Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234703/send-signal-from-parent-process-to-child-in-c

Comment: @prabhu Thanks a lot!